# How to limit users of a service to a specific program

Tags: security, client-server, android-development

I have built an android game - I would like to add a "high score" leaderboard to it, such that people can show off how high they managed to score. How should I design it so that people can't "hack" it by decompiling it and sending a fake score? I don't believe android has a TPM module yet for most devices, so I can't store a password there (even if I could, how could I insert it there without it being detected in transmission?).

I could obfuscate the code, but that isn't going to prevent hacking, only deter it.

I will be using a secured connection, so I shouldn't have any network-sniffing issues.

I am not sure if it would be better to post it under android or security instead of here, but I think this is the correct place since I am asking for a design.

Comment: Given that Android is essentially Linux, one could patch the kernel (or add some code) on his Android device to circumvent your thing. So I would simply not bother.

Comment: Such things are always a matter of weighing effort vs. gains. Hacking the kernel and manipulating your Android phone just to cheat at an online high score seems a *bit* excessive, so there *might* be some value in taking basic countermeasures.

Comment: [Here's a lengthy discussion on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13854425/3372061).

Comment: I'm guessing calculating the score server-side instead of client-side is not an option?

Comment: to clarify, I am not looking to secure the entire application code, but perhaps just the password used to connect or similar (asking for alternative options). Calculating the score could be done on the server if all the game input commands are sent, but that would only shift the target, not make it more difficult.

Comment: What makes you think your "secured connection" prevents network-sniffing? The password is on the device in the user's hand and if you use standard libraries for the connection there are standard ways of sniffing them. I would just use something like AES with a hard-coded password, because it is easy and gives you obfuscation that is close to as good as it gets.

Comment: @nwp - I am asking how to hide the password, or perhaps create it dynamically, or something - basically those require something in addition to the actual network traffic, so I am looking to do that.